# Help with modular equation for division of $n^2$ with $n+1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am having trouble understanding the solution for the following problem:

Show that when dividing n x n by n+1, the remainder is always 1.

I have attempted to solve it using modular equations:

$$n \times n \equiv r \pmod{n+1}$$

Which simplifies to:

$$n^2 \equiv r \pmod{n+1}$$

However, when trying different values for n, I am not getting the expected result of the remainder always being 1.
Can anyone please explain or provide a step-by-step breakdown of how this solution works for different values of $n$? I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on this matter.

Comment: $n\equiv-1\pmod{n+1}$

Comment: could you elaborate? @Thissitehasbecomeadump.

Comment: $\!\!\bmod n\!+\!1\!:\,\ n\!+\!1\equiv 0\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{n\equiv -1}\Rightarrow \color{#c00}n^2\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^2\equiv 1\,$ via [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) in the linked dupe. $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

One way to show that $n^2\equiv 1 \pmod{n+1}$ is to write $n^2$ as
$$n^2=(n+1)(n-1) +{\color{red}1}$$

Here, you can see that the remainder of the division of $n^2$ by $n+1$ is $\color{red}1$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

$$n^2=[(n+1)-1]^2=(n+1)^2-2(n+1)+1\equiv 0^2-2\times 0+1\equiv 1 \quad  \pmod {n+1}$$

Comment: this looks complicated, could you share some comments on your approach? appreciate it.

Comment: If you're going to use modular arithmetic, it's surely easier to do $n^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n+1}$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

Modular arithmetic seems to be slightly overkill. One can use long division as a very elementary approach. What I'm about to show is slightly related to the approaches shown in the other answers.

$$\frac{n^2}{n+1} = \frac{n^2 \color{red}{-1+1}}{n+1}$$

Now we split the fractions and use difference of squares to get,

$$\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}$$

I hope it's clear from this point what to do next.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).